Galilean boost operator for quantum multi-particle system
If I have a two particle system with with a potential of form $V(x_1,x_2)$, is it possible to apply the galilean boost operator to only a single coordinate? Essentially, is it possible to move only a single in a two-particle system?
Surely given some wave function $\Psi(x_1,x_2)$ of a Hamiltonian $$\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p^2_1}}{2m_1} + \frac{\hat{p^2_1}}{2m_1} + \hat{V}(x_1,x_2),$$ the boosted wave function $$\Psi'(x_1,x_2,t) = \hat{\Gamma}_1 \hat{\Gamma}_2\Psi(x_1,x_2)$$ will satisfy the TDSE. Or so I think. I'm not sure if this can only apply if $\Psi(x_1,x_2)$ can be written as a tensor product of steady states for each particle individually (or in a linear combination of products that obeys whatever particle-type statistics it must obey).
My question is essentially will $\Gamma_1 \psi(x_1,x_2)$ obey the TDSE, and if not why?
